# What is the fastest way to parse xml files in parallel?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing

I need to use XmlDocument or HAP to parse several files, what is the fastest way to do it? I have an i7 processor, but the processor is using hardly 30% no matter how many threads I use. Each thread parses a different file.

Comment: May be speed is limited by HDD? How big are your XML's? Try to store XMLs on RAMdisk (only to test speed of parsing)

Comment: Yup, your read speed is probably the bottleneck here. Load them into memory first if that's an option.

Comment: @yamen: Reading them on separate threads is apparently what the OP has tried, as stated in the post...

Comment: How many xml files?  Are you buffering the input correctly?  How many cores/threads? (Some are 2/4).

Comment: I have i7 4 cores 4 hyperthreading. I am buffering correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Parse()` is faster than `XmlDocument.LoadXml()` for parsing XML strings, and XElement.Load() will parse directly from a file. You may also find LINQ to XML much easier to use.

But if you want to work with XmlDocument, then you can use

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(XElement.Load(someFileName).ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting));
```

And as others suggested, you probably won't hit 100% CPU utilization since the i7 may parse much faster than the hard disk can send data.

Comment: Use thread pooling to overcome the thread creation and dispose overhead.

Comment: Consider using Task Parallel Library [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537608.aspx] and Parallel.ForEach() loop to enable data parallelism over any IEnumerable data source.